# TestNG expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp using enum

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am using the `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp` propery on the @Test annotation to test the exception message using enum but it is not working.  Does enum is supported ?

Below code deoesn't work.  Since the  error message is very long, i don't want to hardcode inline like `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "very long message"`

```
@Test(description = "Some description", expectedExceptions=CutomException.class,
     expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = MyEnum.CUSTOM_ERROR.toString())
{
 //test case 

}
```

Any idea how to use expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp with enum ?

Comment: The issue here is that the `@Test` annotation parameters are processed at compile time, but the `toString()` method call for the enum will only be executed at runtime

Comment: Any idea, How do we acheive it then? I just don't want to put the entire long error messages on the test files.

Comment: You may use static as a workaround, like: `private static final String CUSTOM_ERROR = MyEnum.CUSTOM_ERROR.toString();`, so `CUSTOM_ERROR` is a compile-time constant

Comment: Hey . I just checked its not working. because even the final variable will be evaluated at runtime.  you can check from your side too.